# Basic Objective C Problem

Tags: objective-c

In my driver class I call this method:

```
NSMutableArray *test = [[myGrid getLoc:5 : 5] getAdjacentLocation: 2 : 2];
```

The header and the first line of the implementation of getAdjacentLocation is:

```
- (NSMutableArray*) getAdjacentLocation: (int)w: (int)h{
    NSLog(@"checkpoint");
}
```

The implementation of getLoc is:

```
- (Location*)getLoc:(int)i : (int)j {
    NSLog(@"check");
    return (Location*)locations[i][j];
}
```

This is suppose to return a location out of an 2d array. Although the NSLog is call, I dont think it returns it properly?
(can I get 2d arrays with properties?)

I init locations like this

int x = 0;
            int y = 0;

```
        //row
        for(int i = 0; i < 1000; i+=40){
            //column
            for(int j = 0; j < 1000; j+=40) {

                locations[y][x] = [[Location alloc] initWithPosition:CGPointMake(i, j)];

                NSLog(@"%@" ,NSStringFromCGPoint(locations[y][x].locPosition));

                y++;


            }

            x=0;
            y++;

        }
```

I could be doing something stupid with memory management as this is completely new to me.

The first statement in this method of getadjacentlocation is not executed. Why?
This is probably a very stupid mistake, but can anyone help me out here?
Thanks.

Comment: Could you post the `getLoc` method definition?

Comment: `[myGrid getLoc:5 : 5]` could be returning nil. Sending a message to nil in Objective-C will result in no method being called and a return value of nil.

Comment: @Brigham: Exactly my thought.

Comment: @John: How do you initialize `locations`?

Comment: thats very likely because when I try to access a locations position it just returns me (0,0) as the point.

Comment: In your location initialization code, you never increment x, only y, meaning that most of the elements of your 2d array are undefined.

Comment: @John: Returning (0,0) when it shouldn't means that the `CGPoint` is null.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your `getLoc::` method is probably returning `nil`, because in your locations initialization code, you're only incrementing `y`, not `x`, leaving most of the elements of location undefined. Fix your loop to increment x inside the column for loop.

Answer (score 0):

Obj-c methods are supposed to have parameters and names. You ought to name your parameters, so your method should be declared `getAdjacentLocationWidth:(int)w height:(int)h` and called like `[object getAdjacentLocationWidth:2 height:2];`. I added the width and height words to the method name so you can tell which parameter is which.

(You should also go and name the parameters in the `-getLoc::` method, too.)

**Note**: edited down from an answer that was an incorrect answer to a recommendation of named parameters.

Comment: dident work :( besides all my other methods dont have additional names and they work fine. thanks for the response though

Comment: How didn't it work? Can you post an update to the question with more of your code and any errors or warnings you get?

Comment: Objective C methods don't _require_ labels for every parameter, although they are a good idea. http://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/Cocoa/Conceptual/ObjectiveC/Chapters/ocObjectsClasses.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/TP30001163-CH11-SW6

Comment: @Brigham: I know they aren't required, but there's no reason not to use them.

Comment: Perhaps, but adding them isn't going to fix whatever's going on with this question.

Comment: @Brigham: I guess not, seeing your discussion with Evan on the question. I've never not used named parameters, so I didn't know what the compiler would do with that. Is my answer unhelpful to the point it ought to be deleted?

Comment: @CajunLuke I agree with you that he should be using labels, so IMO just clean it up to that effect (i.e. saying that it won't fix the bug, but it is good style and more maintainable.)

Comment: He absolutely should be using labels.  That code is unreadable and incurs additional learning headaches for anyone new to the codebase.